# Как можно записать в .txt файл вывод консоли?

Tags: java

```
package package1.com;

import java.io.*;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Device device1 = new Device();
        Directory dir = device1.createDirect("Dir1", 10, " ");
        dir.addFile("File1.1", 10);
        dir.addFile("File1.2", 10);
        dir.addFile("File1.3", 10);

        Directory dir1 = device1.createDirect("Dir2", 6, " ");
        dir1.addFile("File2.1", 2);
        dir1.addFile("File2.2", 2);
        dir1.addFile("File2.3", 2);

        Directory dir2 = device1.createDirect("Dir3", 7, " ");
        dir2.addFile("File3.1", 2);
        dir2.addFile("File3.2", 2);
        dir2.addFile("File3.3", 2);

        Directory dir3 = device1.createDirect("Dir4", 7, " ");
        dir3.addFile("File4.1", 2);
        dir3.addFile("File4.2", 2);
        dir3.addFile("File4.3", 2);

        device1.showDir();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("notes5.txt"))) {
            String text;
            while (!(text = br.readLine()).equals("ESC")) {

                bw.write(text + "\n");
                bw.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Это вывод консоли, но почему-то он не хочет записывать его. В чем ошибка? И возможно ли, чтобы записывание прекращалось автоматически, не прописывая ESC. Просто в дальнейшем я хочу данный метод навесить на кнопку, чтобы при нажатии было автосохранение в файл.

```
Dir1 
Имя файла : File1.1  Размер файла: 10
Имя файла : File1.2  Размер файла: 10
Имя файла : File1.3  Размер файла: 10
Кол-во элементов: 3  Длина массива: 10
Dir2 
Имя файла : File2.1  Размер файла: 2
Имя файла : File2.2  Размер файла: 2
Имя файла : File2.3  Размер файла: 2
Кол-во элементов: 3  Длина массива: 6
Dir3 
Имя файла : File3.1  Размер файла: 2
Имя файла : File3.2  Размер файла: 2
Имя файла : File3.3  Размер файла: 2
Кол-во элементов: 3  Длина массива: 7
Dir4 
Имя файла : File4.1  Размер файла: 2
Имя файла : File4.2  Размер файла: 2
Имя файла : File4.3  Размер файла: 2
Кол-во элементов: 3  Длина массива: 7
```

Comment: Может лучше создать буффер?

Comment: @Duoxx Если не сложно,можно по подробнее.Или материал какой-нибудь для чтения.

Comment: Это когда сначала все просчитываешь, затем выводишь или параллельно

Comment: @Duoxx я же так и прописал

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов записываешь все в строку - эту строку выводишь в консоли, ее же записываешь в файл. в чем проблема?

Comment: @Санаев как записывать уже я понял..А как из того что выводится сделать строку.Данные вывода могут меняться .

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов не понимаю в чем проблема? Используй StringBuffer и через append добавляй

Comment: @Санаев разве не через scanner мне сначала надо отсканировать выведенное в консоле,А потом уже через FileOutputStream сохранить в файл?

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов я же говорю после считывания с консоли, записываете в строку. В общем разбирайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

```
Разобрался.

        public void saveProject(String name)throws FileNotFoundException {
        Directory current = firstDir;
        File  file = new File(name);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream printStream1 = new PrintStream(fileOutputStream);

        System.setOut(printStream1);
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.getNameDir() + " ");
            current.display();
            current = current.getNextDir();
        }
        }
```